# initialize variables in structure in an array

Tags: c

I created array of structs and I created them in the function `config_course_list` with a file that contains courses information.
I tested variables at the of the function and it is correct. However when I call this function in `main`, the `*courses` has size 1, contains only one struct. Which I can print `courses[0].code` and `courses[0].description`, but fail to print `courses[1].code` and `description`.

What should I do to make it work?

---

config_course_list:

```
int config_course_list(Course **courselist_ptr, char *config_filename) {
    FILE *f;
    char buff[INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    f = fopen(config_filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("file");
    }

    fgets(buff,INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE+1,f);
    int size = atoi(buff);

    *courselist_ptr = (Course *)malloc(size * sizeof(Course));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        courselist_ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(Course));
    }

    int index = 0;
    char *token[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        token[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    }

    while (fgets(buff,INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE+1, f) != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(courselist_ptr[index]->code, strtok(buff, " "));
        strcpy(token[index],strtok(NULL, "\n"));
        courselist_ptr[index]->description=token[index];
        index ++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

---

main:

```
Course *courses; 
int num_courses = config_course_list(&courses, argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", courses[1].code);
```

---

struct course:

```
struct course{
    char code[7];
    char *description;
};
```

Comment: If `fopen()` fails, this code prints an error message, then continues as if everything is OK.... You seem to be missing a `typedef` for `Course`.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read this: [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: All `int` better were `size_t`. `sizeof (char)` equals `1` by definition. No need to cast `void`-pointers, like `malloc()`'s result.

Comment: Why `+1` to the buffer size passed to `fgets()`?

Answer (score 2):

Delete these lines:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        courselist_ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(Course));
    }
```

what is the purpose of above loop ? It looks like you want to create 2D array ... not this way.

Your aim is to create 1D array and you do it by

```
*courselist_ptr = (Course *)malloc(size * sizeof(Course));
```

and it is enough, the array was created now you can fill it by some data.

When you created 1D array, 
and `p` points to the first element of this array you have two ways
to access *i-th* element:

```
p[i]
```

or

```
*(p + i)
  ^    - p is pointer to first element of array
```

In your case `p` is `*courselist_ptr`
so if you want to read/write `code` member you can use:

```
(*courselist_ptr)[i].code 
(*courselist_ptr + i)->code
(*(*courselist_ptr + i)).code
```

so you have to replace
`courselist_ptr[index]->code` by `(*courselist_ptr)[index].code` and `courselist_ptr[index]->description` by `(*courselist_ptr)[index].description`.